# how to change share point workflow are complete

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, i created an info path form and submitted it to SharePoint.

With Microsoft SharePoint designer i created a workflow for this form.

At this workflow I implemented removing permission from some group and getting contribute access to 2 person.

Now after 3 month, there are 450 item in form library.
And i want to add another person to (2 persons) that have contribute access.
So, i changed workflow in SharePoint designer.

It is correct for new items that created after this time. but i want this new workflow set to old item that before 3 month created!

how can I do that?

Comment: I *think* you are asking how do you add the new person to the permissions that were created previously?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question correctly. That you want to add the new person to the existing permissions. Then don't do it through workflow.

Assuming that your 450 forms mean that there are 450 groups that need to be changed, the easiest way is to create a list of the group names and use PowerShell to add the new user to all of the groups.

Better still if you can, would be to create an Active Directory Security Group with the 3 people in it and apply *that* to all of the SharePoint groups. Then you will never have to go through the same exercise again as you can simply change the AD group and the SharePoint groups will all be correct.